# Django rest framework filter by datetime field

Tags: python, django-models, django-views, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

In `django-rest-framework` how can I filter a `datetimefield` using greater than filters.

```
class RestaurantList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = RestaurantSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        #This returns equals but if I use the > sign it does not work 
        return Restaurant.objects.filter(last_update_time = "2016-08-03")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `gt` statement like this:

```
def get_queryset(self): 
    return Restaurant.objects.filter(last_update_time__gt=datetime(2016, 08, 03)
```

For more information see [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#gt)